# Non uniform outer layer of grids

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw grids without the outer layer. Here is the code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=2cm,color=gray] (.2,.2) grid (10.75,10.75);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this[image]. As one can see, the outerlayer is not uniformly placed. Can anyone please point out how to make it uniform? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by outer layer? That is not obvious

Comment: The outer line I mean.

Comment: Do you a "box" to surround your grid, don't you?

Comment: what happens if you do this `\draw[step=2cm,color=gray] (.2,.2) grid (10.75,10.75) (.2,.2) rectangle(10.75,10.75);`

Comment: @felix Try this: `\draw[step=2cm,color=gray] (1,1) grid +(10,10);`

Comment: Do you want the grid to be centered in the rectangle you create? Is this what you mean with "uniform"?